# Hibernate @Version for Parent entity

Tags: hibernate

I want to implement a standard functionality of a parent that acts like an owning entity of its children, like in the pair `Order` - `OrderLine`. I would like to modify order AND order lines in one view and provide for an optimistic locking based on version field in `Order` only. I would also like to use indexed list as a collection with index stored in the database.

I tried different settings, but none of them worked. My setup is:

Database script:

```
CREATE TABLE Site_Order (
    order_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    order_number INT NOT NULL,
    version BIGINT NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO Site_Order (order_number, version) VALUES (1, 1);

CREATE TABLE Order_Line (
    order_line_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    order_id INT NOT NULL,
    product_name VARCHAR(100),
    idx INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES Site_Order(order_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO Order_Line (order_id, product_name, idx) VALUES (1, "Coffee", 0);
```

Entities:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "site_order")
public class SiteOrder implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer orderId;
    private int orderNumber;
    private long version;
    private List<OrderLine> orderLines = new ArrayList<OrderLine>(0);

    //constructors, fileds getters and setters

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval=true)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.DELETE, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @OrderColumn(name="idx", nullable=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="order_id", nullable=false)
    public List<OrderLine> getOrderLines() {
        return this.orderLines;
    }

    protected void setOrderLines(List<OrderLine> orderLines) {
        this.orderLines = orderLines;
    }

    public void addOrderLine(OrderLine ol) {
        orderLines.add(ol);
        if (!orderLine.getSiteOrder().equals(this)) {
            orderLine.getSiteOrder().getOrderLines().remove(orderLine);
            orderLine.setSiteOrder(this);
        }
    }

    public void removeOrderLine(OrderLine ol) {
        orderLines.remove(ol);
        if (orderLine.getSiteOrder().equals(this)) {
            orderLine.setSiteOrder(null);
        }
    }

}

@Entity @Table(name = "order_line")
public class OrderLine implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer orderLineId;
    private SiteOrder siteOrder;
    private String productName;

    //constructors, fileds getters and setters

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", nullable = false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    public SiteOrder getSiteOrder() {
        return this.siteOrder;
    }

    public void setSiteOrder(SiteOrder siteOrder) {
        this.siteOrder = siteOrder;
        if ((siteOrder != null) && (!siteOrder.getOrderLines().contains(this))) {
            siteOrder.addOrderLine(this);
        }
    }

}
```

Typical usage is (1) to add new order line to existing order, in which order version gets updated and (2) modification of order line's properties, like quantity, product, price, etc. which do not affect order version.

(1):

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
SiteOrder s = (SiteOrder)session.get(SiteOrder.class, Integer.valueOf(1));
OrderLine o = new OrderLine();
o.setProductName("Cup");
s.addOrderLine(o);
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

(2):

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
SiteOrder s = (SiteOrder)session.get(SiteOrder.class, Integer.valueOf(1));
s.getOrderLines().get(0).setProductName("Tea");
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

Is there a way to achieve a general solution to the abovementioned versioning problem in Hibernate?